# Position fixed padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get two divs to stick together at the bottom of the page using position:fixed.  The problem is when I put padding on the #feedbackTab, it repeats the #feedbackTab from the bottom of the page to the place where I want it.  How can I have #feedbackTab on top of #feedbackBody with both of them fixed to the bottom of the page?

```
#feedbackTab {
background-image:url(../img/feedback_12.png);
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:300px;
margin:0;
width:960px;
height:34px;
}

#feedbackBody {
background-image:url(../img/Feedback_bkg_14.png);
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
width:960px;
height:292px;
margin:0;
}

<div id="feedback">
        <div id="feedbackTab"></div>
        <div id="feedbackBody">
            <div id="comments">
                <h2>Comments/Suggestions</h2>
                <input class="commentsTxt" type="text" name="Comments"><br \>
                <input id="commentsSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div><!-- end comments -->
            <div id="problems">
                <h2>Problems?</h2><br \>
                <label id="email">Email:</label><input class="emailBox" type="text" name="Email"><br \>
                <label id="problem">Problem:&nbsp;</label><input class="problemBox" type="text" name="Comments"><br \>
                <input id="problemsSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div><!-- end problems -->
      </div><!-- end feedbackBody -->
    </div><!-- end feedback -->
```

Comment: When you say 'stick together at the bottom of the page', could you explain what you mean a bit more?

Comment: So the #feedbackTab is supposed to sit higher (ontop) of #feedbackBody. Pete, that's the stack order. I'm talking about the vertical position on the page. I want the bottom of #feedbackTab attached to the top of #feedbackBody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put them in a container div to hold everything together like so:

CSS:

```
#tabContainer{
    width:700px;
}
.tab{
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}
#feedbackTab{
    background-color:red;
}
#tab2{
    background-color:green;
}
#tab3{
    background-color:yellow;
}
#feedbackBody{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabContainer">
    <div id="feedbackTab" class="tab">FeedBack</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">Tab2</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">Tab3</div>

    <div id="feedbackBody">
        This is the feedback body
        <br/>lorem ipsum
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="button">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately JSFiddle seems to be down right now so I can't mock it up or test it for you. I hope this helps though!

**EDIT:** I found a replacement test bed: http://cssdesk.com/y7Hb2